# Cordova setup with android not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android

For cordova project i set android system variables(ANDROID_HOME,PATH) in bash_profile. My cordova project is sucessfully build and run but after two days it's getting an error:(system variables are not getting set again in bash_profile)

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.



export ANDROID_HOME=/home/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

I don't know what's wrong. Please help me out....

Comment: I have those set in my ~/.bash_aliases as `export ANDROID_HOME="bla/path/bla/android-sdk-linux"`. I dont know if that makes any difference

Comment: is that works? but i  set environment with bash_profile after some days it get disappear  automatically ,i dont have idea about ~/.bash_aliases can you give any reference about that

Comment: Exactly the same lines, in your case `export ANDROID_HOME=/home/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/`

`export PATH=${PATH}:/home/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools`

Comment: ok, but now my ~adb command is working and also ~android is work that means my tools,platform-tools and ANDROID_HOME path is allready set ,but on project build or run it show your path variables are not set. My all system paths are set but i cant build my project, on build time it show error.

Comment: Sounds like it should be working, have you made sure that the permissions for your user are correct? That said I would expect everything to be working now.

Comment: how can i check permissions for user are correct?

Comment: Personally rather than checking one at a time I would use `tree -pufid` to check all subdirectories, as long as each group has at least read it should work.

Comment: on  ~tree -pufid  show long log which i can not understand what i do with that..